# Can't set up printer

Tags: printing

I'm trying to set up an HP OFficejet Pro 8500 A909a on my Windows XP machine over the network.

I know the IP address of the printer but it's unclear to me how to set it up based on that. I have no idea how to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: What have you tried? have you created a local TCP/IP port? You really need to give some details. If your looking for basic instructions on how to setup a printer this is not the place.

Comment: No, I haven't set up a local TCP/IP port. How would I do that? (I said I have no idea how to troubleshoot this problem.) If this isn't the place, what is?

Comment: Super user would be your best bet. This isn't troubleshooting, this is a complete lack of knowledge on a subject. Which is fine I can't fault someone for wanting to learn. But this site is for IT professionals, meaning we have already been to school or spent a significant amount of time in the field. Also people here will assume you already know the basics when answering your questions.

Comment: Either talk to your system administrator or read the printer's manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go [HERE](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=228&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3752456), download the latest drivers and documentation - then follow the instructions. The first thing you're going to have to figure out is how to set an IP address on the printer, once that's done and you can ping it from your client machine then it's really just the driver that needs to be in place and you can connect the two.

Next time consider this kind of question for superuser perhaps?

Comment: I've already tried doing exactly that and it didn't work. It told me the printer was on a different gateway from my workstation, which is not true. I'll try superuser.